# What is the difference between /usr/include/linux and /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/

Tags: c, linux, header

I'm very new to native C programming and now I'm trying to configure my IDE to set up include paths correctly. Since I would like to navigate by `sys/xxx.h` files I added

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

to my include path. But there is also `/usr/include/linux` which seems contains the same headers also. So what is the difference between them? And which one should I use actually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can tell you immediately that the directories `/usr/include/linux` and `/usr/include/asm` should never be included in a list of system header directories.  The headers in those directories are meant to be used as `#include <linux/whatever.h>` or `#include <asm/whatever.h>`, not as `#include <whatever.h>`.

The rest of the answer to this question depends on exactly which "distribution" of Linux you are using, so I can't just say it.  Fortunately, there is a way to get the compiler to tell you.  Run this command (exactly as shown) in a terminal window:

```
LC_ALL=C gcc -v -xc -E /dev/null 2>&1 | 
    sed -ne '/search starts here/,/End of search list/p'
```

You will get output that looks something like this, but the details may be slightly different:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

The directories listed are the directories you should configure your IDE to look for system headers in, for purpose of looking up declarations and whatnot.  However, you should *not* configure your IDE to pass any of these directories to the compiler as `-I` directories.  It already knows to use them, it doesn't need to be told again, and telling it again can mess things up (for instance, the *order* of the above directories matters).

As an application programmer you don't need to worry about which headers "belong" in which directories.  That's entirely the compiler and C library developers and Linux distribution maintainers' task.